# Is Djokovic - Federer 2019 the first Wimbledon match to have a tiebreak in the final set?

Tags: tennis, tie-breaker

Right now, a tiebreak is being played in the Wimbledon 2019 men's final between Djokovic and Federer. This is different from how it was before; in past Wimbledon tournaments, players were required to win the final set by 2 games, leading to the 70-68 score in the final set between [Mahut and Isner in 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isner%E2%80%93Mahut_match_at_the_2010_Wimbledon_Championships).

Is this the first occurrence of a tiebreak in the final set on Wimbledon?

Answer (score 2):

After some research (which took longer than the final tiebreak itself), the [Women's fourth round match between Muchova and Pliskova](https://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/scores/stats/2406.html) almost featured a final tiebreak, but the set ended in 13-11.

There *was* a final tiebreak in the [Gentlemen's Doubles third round match Kontinen & Peers vs. Ram & Salisbury](https://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/scores/stats/3305.html), so the Men's final was not the first occurrence, but it was the first occurrence in the Singles.

That is, unless the tiebreak rules were different in ancient times; I'm not too sure about that.

Answer (score -1):

2019 is the year when tie-break in the 5th was introduced at both Australian Open and Wimbledon
The Djokovic-Federer final was the first Wimbledon mens's singles match to end in a tie-break
As @Glorfindel pointed out, in doubles it occurred couple days earlier in the 3rd Round

At Australian though, after reaching 6-6, a tie-break until 10 is played (margin of 2 is required obviously).

So French Open remains the only Grand Slam tournament without a tie-break in the 5th.

Before 1971, there was no tie-break in any of the sets actually :)